# Why does setuptools need to write bytecode?

Tags: python, virtualenv, setuptools

If you try to run `virtualenv` with the environmental variable `PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=true` set, it gives this error:

`The PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE environment variable is not compatible with setuptools. Either use --distribute or unset PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE.`

Why does setuptools require the ability to write bytecode?

I don't particularly like having `.pyc` files around, so I like to prevent it from being written.

(I'm not asking how to get around this; that's trivial: just add `PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=""` at the beginning of any command that requires the flag to be unset, or unset it globally)

Answer (score 1):

Use a recent version of `virtualenv` and you will not see this error.

Comment: Could you say how recent?

Comment: @keflavich please specify what you have an on what platform, as these important details are missing. My `virtualenv --version` reports `13.1.2` on OS X.